# Ionic Firebase Data change when app is closed

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app in this app I have many question which user can answer and show the percentage of answer user give, but when user answer multiple questions and close the app. Then when the user come again the question show from starting, is their anyway from which will show the questions to user where the user end? Thanks

Newp.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { QuestionPage } from '../question/question';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-newp',
  templateUrl: 'newp.html',
})
export class NewpPage {

  @ViewChild('slides') slides: any;

    hasAnswered: boolean = false;
    score: number = 0;
    stateimage:any;
    slideOptions: any;
  cli:any;
  showclicks:boolean;
  hideMe: any;
  clickvalue1: number;
  clickvalue2: number;
  clickPercentage1: number;
  clickPercentage2: number;
  current_wouldclicks: number;
  current_ratherclicks: number;
  wouldclicks: number = 0;
  ratherclicks: number = 0;
  question_str: any;
  item_key: any;
  firebase_flag: boolean;
 questions:Observable<any>;
  wouldquestion : any;
  ratherquestion : any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private alertCtrl: AlertController, public navParams: NavParams, public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,  public afd: AngularFireDatabase, public http: HttpClient) {

  this.clickvalue1 =  0;
    this.clickvalue2 = 0;
    this.clickPercentage1 = 0;
    this.clickPercentage2 = 0;
    this.ratherclicks = 0;
    this.wouldclicks = 0;
    this.questions = this.afd.list('Questions').valueChanges();       // <=====  Question is coming from there .
    this.cli = "";
    this.showclicks = false;
}
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad NewpPage');
  }

  nextSlide(){
    this.showclicks = false;
        this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
        this.slides.slideNext();
        this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }

  presentPrompt() {
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: 'Add Your Question',
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'would',
        placeholder: 'Would You ',
      },
      {
        name: 'rather',
        placeholder: 'Rather'
      }
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Add',
        role: 'add',
        handler: data => {
          this.wouldquestion = data.would;
          this.ratherquestion = data.rather;
          this.afd.list("Questions/").push({
            would:this.wouldquestion,
            rather:this.ratherquestion,
            ratherclick:this.ratherclicks,
            wouldclick:this.wouldclicks
          });
        }
      },
          ]
  });
  alert.present();
}




  show(clicks)
  {
    this.showclicks = true;

    if(this.showclicks)
    {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.nextSlide()
    }, 500);
    }
  }

    clickedButton(index,paramString) 
    {
      this.question_str = paramString

      firebase.database().ref('Questions/').on('value',data => {
         data.forEach( item => 
         {
            if(item.val().would == this.question_str)
            {
              this.item_key = item.key;
              this.firebase_flag = true;
              this.wouldclicks = item.val().wouldclick;
              this.ratherclicks = item.val().ratherclick;
              this.wouldclicks++;
            }
            else if(item.val().rather == this.question_str)
            {
              this.item_key = item.key;
              this.firebase_flag = false;
              this.wouldclicks = item.val().wouldclick;
              this.ratherclicks = item.val().ratherclick;
              this.ratherclicks++;
            }
         });
    });

    if(this.firebase_flag == true)
    {
    firebase.database().ref('Questions/' + this.item_key).child("wouldclick").set(this.wouldclicks);

    }
    else
    {
    firebase.database().ref('Questions/' + this.item_key).child("ratherclick").set(this.ratherclicks);

    }
    switch (index) {
      case 1:
        this.clickPercentage1 = Math.round(this.wouldclicks / (this.wouldclicks + this.ratherclicks) * 100);
        this.clickPercentage2 = Math.round(this.ratherclicks / (this.wouldclicks + this.ratherclicks) * 100);
        break;
      case 2:
        this.clickPercentage1 = Math.round(this.wouldclicks / (this.wouldclicks + this.ratherclicks) * 100);
        this.clickPercentage2 = Math.round(this.ratherclicks / (this.wouldclicks + this.ratherclicks) * 100);
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

Newp.html

```
<ion-header color="grey">

  <ion-navbar color="grey" center>
    <ion-title >Would You Rather ?</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons class="bttn" right><button right class="bttn" (click)="presentPrompt()">  <ion-icon color="light" name="md-more"></ion-icon></button></ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content  class="background">

    <ion-slides #slides>



        <ion-slide *ngFor="let question of questions | async; let i = index;">
           <!--  <div class="orca">
                                      this is for or round 

              </div> -->
            <!-- <h3>Question {{i+1}}</h3> -->
          <div class="quizcontainer" >

          <div class="upper" text-center (click)="show(question.ckc)" (click)="clickedButton(1,question.would)" >
                <p *ngIf="showclicks" style="color: white" item-end class="p1">{{ clickPercentage1 }}% </p>
                <p  class="q1" style="text-align: center;">{{question.would}}</p>

          </div>

          <div class="or" style="color: white" ><p class="pp">OR </p></div>


          <div class="down" text-center (click)="show(question.ckc)" (click)="clickedButton(2,question.rather)" >
                  <p *ngIf="showclicks" style="color: white" item-end class="p1">{{ clickPercentage2 }}% </p>
              <p  class="q1" >{{question.rather}}</p>
          </div>

          </div>


        </ion-slide>



      </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

[image: Firebase Data base this is few question but i have 100]

Answer (score 0):

I think we can store the last state of the user action in the local application store or alike and use it when user open the application again.

Comment: not understand . local application store mean local storage ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried local storage? Try using npm package @ngx-pwa/local-storage.